# C# linq operator as variable

Tags: c#, linq

(In theory) We have the following query:

```
var variableDate = DateTime.Parse("Nov 2, 2021")

var results = (from x in db.FooBar
               where x.Date == variableDate
               select x).ToList();
```

We can simply modify the *variableDate* to 11/3/21, 11/4/21, etc. to return results for different dates.

The question is can we use this same query to return all results **after** *variableDate* with some modification to the operator(s)/variable(s)?  For example including the operator (> or ==) within *variableDate* (let's call it *variableDateFormula*):

*> 11/2/2021*

or

*== 11/2/2021*

This way we can simply call the same query with the same variable to return results for different operators:

```
var results = (from x in db.FooBar
               where x.Date variableDateFormula 
               select x).ToList();
```

I know the suggestion above will not work, it is just for visualization.  I have a query that takes up 9 lines and has 8 different iterations depending on 3 values passed into the function.  I would love to avoid writing basically the same query 8 times and taking up ~70 lines, and instead dynamically change the operators/criteria to have only 1 query.

Comment: You may want to look at Expression Trees

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the operator is just syntactic sugar for a function call and you can change that function, for example with a lambda:

```
var equalFunc = ((d1,d2) => d1 == d2);
var greaterFunc = ((d1,d2) => DateTime.Compare(d1, d2) > 0);

var actualFunc = greaterFunc; // Insert logic here to choose the appropriate function
```

Then your select becomes

```
from x in db.FooBar
where actualFunc(x.Date, variableDate)
select x
```

Comment: Really? Without LINQKit it would never work.

Comment: @TToni please see edit, the query loads forever - I don't see any issues

Comment: @TToni I had to first run the initial linq query with no filters to capture the potential records from the database, and then run the new filter expressions on the list returned from that first query.  When the filters were included in the first query it would just load forever.  thank you for the help

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv: It really depends on the LINQ provider if this works or not. OP has not given context, but the `db.FooBar` is a strong hint of course which I overlooked (I'm used to work with Linq2Obj, where this should be totally fine).

Answer (score 0):

Yes. The LINQ is just building an `ExpressionTree` that Entity Framework translates in to SQL, so you can use other expressions or lambdas as parameters that get inserted into the tree, like in this LINQpad example:

```
void Main()
{
    var aDate = new DateTime(2002, 1, 1);

    GetResults(d => d.TheDate == aDate).Dump();
    GetResults(d => d.TheDate <= aDate).Dump();
    GetResults(d => d.TheDate > aDate).Dump();
}
   
IEnumerable<Data> GetResults(Func<Data, bool> op)
{
    var data = new List<Data>
    {
        new Data{TheDate = new DateTime(2000,1,1)},
        new Data{TheDate = new DateTime(2001,1,1)},
        new Data{TheDate = new DateTime(2002,1,1)},
        new Data{TheDate = new DateTime(2003,1,1)},
    };
    
    return data.Where(d => op(d));
}

public class Data
{
    public DateTime TheDate { get; set; }
}
```

Which produces the following results:

[image]

If you are doing more complex logic in your expressions, the EF Database Provider may not be able to translate the expression to SQL though. There will be limitations. You couldn't for example, do this:

```
GetResults(d => d.TheDate.ToString().Reverse() == "1234");
```

because it wouldn't understand the custom `Reverse` extension method.

Comment: I do not see any ExpressionTree here. How it should work?

Comment: Ahh yes, you are correct. This will not work effectively through Entity Framework.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to use [LINQKit](https://github.com/scottksmith95/LINQKit) for such task. EF Core cannot translate local variable as expression function.

```cs
var variableDate = DateTime.Parse("Nov 2, 2021");

Expression<Func<DateTime, DateTime, bool>> compareFunc = (d1, d2) => d1 > d2;

var results = (from x in db.FooBar
               where compareFunc.Invoke(x.Date, variableDate)
               select x).ToList();
```

For enabling LINQKit for EF Core add the following to the options:

```cs
builder
    .UseSqlServer(connectionString)
    .WithExpressionExpanding(); // enabling LINQKit extension
```

Or if you use other LINQ provider, add `AsExpandable()` at the top of the query:

```cs
var results = (from x in db.FooBar.AsExpandable()
               where compareFunc.Invoke(x.Date, variableDate)
               select x).ToList();
```

Comment: please see edit, the query loads forever - I don't see any issues

Comment: Because you have to use my solution, not others, they are wrong. You have to work with `Expression`, otherwise whole table is populated to the client.

Comment: I had to first run the initial linq query with no filters to capture the potential records from the database, and then run the new filter expressions on the list returned from that first query.  When the filters were included in the first query it would just load forever.  thank you for the help

Comment: How many records in your table? Why server side filters do not help? Maybe you need index on `Date` field?

Comment: Probably you have to show your full query, without abstraction like `FooBar`